# Ansible-playbook :change account password for multiple different user in 100 nos of linux servers

Tags: ansible

i Need to change a couple of account passwords, for example for testuser1 and testuser2,testuser3. however, from the 100+ systems I have, not all of them have both users on them. Some systems have test_user1 and some have test_user2 and sometimes both or none of them.

This is when I start having issues; I created the following playbook below :-

```
---
- name: Set Password
  hosts: test
  user: admin1
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: yes

  tasks:
  - shell: getent passwd testuser1 | wc -l | tr -d ' '
    register: user_exists_testuser1
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: change password for testuser1
    user: name=testuser1 update_password=always 
    password="$1$3Zdze7Vx$ltv6dIsdfrsD7."
    when: user_exists_testuser1.rc == 0

  - shell: getent passwd testuser2 | wc -l | tr -d ' '
    register: user_exists_testuser2
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: change password for testuser2
    user: name=testuser2 update_password=always 
    password="$1$sfddgv6dIxsdfssNt2D4."
    when: user_exists_root.rc == 0

  - shell: getent passwd testuser3 | wc -l | tr -d ' '
    register: user_exists_testuser3
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: change password for testuser3
    user: name=testuser3 update_password=always 
    password="$1$3Zdze7VxDEFv6dHKHKSSt2D3."
    when: user_exists_adminusr.rc == 0
```

**issue on this script :**  **if the user does not exist on the system, it creates it. Is there any way to avoid the creation of the user?**

but password is updating correctly in all servers.can have help on this better code change on this above playbook .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to test for the existence of the user, but because you're using a complex pipeline you're losing the exit code from `getent`. You can test this yourself from the command line (always a good idea when diagnosing this sort of problem).

If I run:

```
$ getent passwd doesnotexist
```

And then check the error code, I see that it reports exit status `2`:

```
$ echo $?
2
```

But if I use your pipeline, I get `0` regardless of whether or not the user exists:

```
$ getent passwd doesnotexist | wc -l | tr -d ' '
$ echo $?
0
```

You should rewrite your test like this so that you can use the exit code reported by `getent`:

```
- shell: getent passwd testuser1
  register: user_exists_testuser1
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: change password for testuser1
  user:
    name: testuser1
    update_password: always 
    password: "$1$3Zdze7VxDEFv6dHKHKSSt2D3."
  when: user_exists_testuser1.rc == 0
```

You could make good use of Ansible loops to reduce the size of your
playbook.

Comment: Thank you . its was working fine .can you help to please share some loop structure for this playbook for 20 user case over all 100 linux machines.